# jQuery UI Position Utility behavior in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm in the process of updating our site to use modern browsers, but I still need to support the cavemen on IE7. I'm experiencing an issue with jQuery UI's position utility. The strange behavior occurs for the Windows 7 OS, using IE 11, emulating IE7 (document mode 7). The strange behavior is nonexistent to me, Windows 8 OS, using IE 11, emulating IE7 (document mode 7).

I need someone to see if this happens to them using either IE7 (not emulated) or with the same setup as our testers experiencing the issue.

The issue occurs when you hover over the missing image element in the upper right of the div. The unordered list shows up once on hover, then any subsequent hovers nothing appears. Either that or the hover never brings up the unordered list to begin with.

Here's a fiddle where the issue should appear if you have a similar work space to what I've mentioned above.

https://jsfiddle.net/bpdxL1e6/

```
  var hoverCollection = $('.current-menu-item');
  $.each(hoverCollection, function(index, object) {
    $(object).hover(function() {
      $(object.lastChild).position({
        my: "right top",
        at: "bottom right",
        of: object.parentElement,
        collision: "flipfit"
      });
    });
  });
```

Its hard to tell the position utility is working at all in jsFiddle, as the purpose of it is mainly to keep the unordered list visible in the viewport on hover.

I have a local html doc on my desktop with the contents of the fiddle to see the effects of the position working.

Here's a link to a download of the full html file.
http://www.filedropper.com/testhtmlfiddle

Comment: Doesn't look like JQuery UI supports ie7 and below https://jqueryui.com/browser-support/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote my own positioning utility. Its called hoverCopter. Supports IE7 as well as all other modern browsers.

```
 var hoverCollection = $('.current-menu-item');
 var hoveringCollection = [];
 $.each(hoverCollection, function(idx, object) {
   hoveringCollection.push(object.lastChild);
 });
 hoverCopter(hoverCollection, hoveringCollection);


 function hoverCopter(objectsToTriggerHover, objectsToHover) {
   $.each(objectsToTriggerHover, function(idx, object) {
     $(object).hover(function() {
       var bool = true;

       var objWidth = $(object).offset().left + $(objectsToHover[idx]).width();
       var winWidth = $(window).width() + $(window).scrollLeft();
       var objHeight = $(object).offset().top + $(objectsToHover[idx]).height();
       var winHeight = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();

       if (objWidth > winWidth) {
         var left = (objWidth - $(object).width() / 2) - winWidth + (winWidth - $(object).offset().left);
         $(objectsToHover[idx]).css({
           'left': -left + 'px'
         });
       } else {
         $(objectsToHover[idx]).css({
           'left': 0 + 'px'
         });
       }
       if (objHeight > winHeight) {
         var top = (objHeight - $(object).height() / 2) - winHeight + (winHeight - $(object).offset().top);
         $(objectsToHover[idx]).css({
           'top': -top + 'px'
         });
         bool = false;
       } else {
         $(objectsToHover[idx]).css({
           'top': 0 + 'px'
         });
       }

       // this is a zIndex hack for IE7 so that the ul display above the images
       var elements = $('[name="homepart_nav_wrap"]');
       var int = 100;
       $.each(elements, function(idx, object) {
         if (bool == false) {
           $(object).css("zIndex", idx);
         } else {
           $(object).css("zIndex", int);
         }
         int--;
       });

     });
   });
 }
```

And here's a jsFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/bpdxL1e6/3/